# I have tick bid/ask data, how can I make candle data from tick's in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse, ticker, candlesticks

I have tick bid/ask data, with columns

```
symbol
timestamp
ask_amount
ask_price
bid_price
bid_amount
```

what kind of query in clickhouse can tick data for equal candles with a length of 1 minute? How can I make candle data from ticks in clickhouse?

I try, but I don't know how to make equal candles

Comment: If you show what you tried, someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: You could try a group by using the toStartOfMinute function on your timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what aggregations you want in the "candle", here are a few arbitrary ones:

```
SELECT 
    symbol,
    toStartOfMinute(timestamp) AS minute,
    max(ask_amount),
    max(ask_price),
    max(bid_price),
    min(bid_price),
    avg(bid_amount)
FROM bids
GROUP BY (minute, symbol)
ORDER BY minute ASC
```